# playback pcm audio pieces

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm trying to play PCM audio samples returned in events by another class.
If I save them in a file and then play it as a stream everythig ia OK. But in realtime playback nothing happens. PlaybackState sets to Stopped.
Here is the code:

```
WaveFormat wf = new WaveFormat(8000, 1);
    MemoryStream ms;
    WaveStream blockAlignedStream;
    WaveOut waveOut;
    short[] PCMSamples = new short[320];

    void StartPlayback()
    {
        ms = new MemoryStream();

        blockAlignedStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new NAudio.Wave.RawSourceWaveStream(ms[1], wf)));

        waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
        waveOut.Init(blockAlignedStream);
        waveOut.Play();
    }

    public void PCMStreamEventHandler(byte[] data)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            var pos = ms.Position;
            codec.Convert(data, PCMSamples);
            ms.Position = ms.Length;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[PCMSamples.Length * 2];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(PCMSamples, 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            ms.Position = pos;
        });
    }
```

Any help on realtime PCM playback would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `BufferedWaveProvider` for this. Just put the bytes received into the `BufferedWaveProvider` as they arrive. Also, you do not need `BlockAlignReductionStream`, and I would strongly advise avoiding function callbacks. Use `WaveOutEvent` instead.